# Invoke method in COM component exposed webservice throwing error

Tags: asp.net, soap, com, webservices-client

I am basically a .NET guy.I don't have much knowledge in VB (COM components). Now,I come across a project where i need to expose a COM dll as a webservice and consume the same in my Asp.NET application.I hosted the webservice on my local development machine and consumed it in a test application.It works just fine.But When i host it on my production server(Server 2003).

It throws 500 internal sever error.When i looked at the stack trace,came to know that Inoke method is throwing error at the below line.

```
object[] results = this.Invoke("Addition", new object[] {
                parameter1,parameter2});
            return ((short)(results[0]));
```

I have registered (example.dll) using command prompt utility as below

regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\example.dll

So,Can anyone suggest me the cause for the following error?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What was the stck trace?

Answer (score 0):

If you are registering a .NET dll that exposes COM interfaces you should be using [REGASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead of REGSRV32.

Comment: Decio, Thanks for the reply but it's not .NET DLL.It is VB 6.0(ActveX dll).Any idea on this?